# PHP fails to load all the POST params

Tags: php, http, phpbb

I'm having an issue with my old phpbb forum. It had been working very well until I changed the server from old php4 to new php5. I cannot retrieve the whole post array. That's pretty strange.

I've used firebug to see what browser is sending and displayed it using print_r.

Here is what I'm sending:

```
addcategory[0]  Create new category
mode    new
name[0] test
name[1000]  
name[1001]  
name[1002]  
and so on
```

Here is what I receive in php using print_r($_POST):

```
Array ( [name] => Array ( [1000] => [1001] => [10002] ...)
```

Shortly speaking, name[0] and mode are not passed at all.

Comment: Do you have another `name[0]` further down the line that might be overwriting the first one?

Comment: No. I've checked that. Perhaps the POST query is too long? There are a few thousands elements sent. What do you think? It could truncate it.

Comment: a few thousand shouldn't be a problem, and stuff shouldn't be truncated this way. Strange.

Comment: That's very odd. I have never had such a situation before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've displayed raw POST data using:

```
print_r(urldecode(file_get_contents('php://input')));
```

All of the params are correctly passed. It seems like php fails to parse these params to place them correctly in $_POST array.

I will parse it myself then and overwrite $_POST array with my "custom" POST data.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get a http-level dump and see what exactly is transferred through the body of your post request. You can use [livehttpheaders](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/) for this.